# How to put lstlisting in a minipage

Tags: listings, environments, minipage

I had a problem creating a new environment that would let me put a `lstlisting` inside a `minipage`. I could create a new environment that sets up the `minipage`, then in the document put a `lstlisting` inside that `minipage`, but I couldn't create environment that did both together.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{listings}    
\lstset{language=SQL,keywordstyle=\underbar,numbers=none}
\newenvironment{egdlisting}%
  {\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}}%
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{egdlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}
select *
  from foo
 where bar = 4;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{egdlisting}

\end{document}
```

Works. The obvious next step, putting the `lstlisting` inside the environment, does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL,keywordstyle=\underbar,numbers=none}
\newenvironment{egdlisting}%
  {\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}\begin{lstlisting}}%
  {\end{lstlisting}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{egdlisting}
select *
  from foo
 where bar = 4;
\end{egdlisting}

\end{document}
```

The error message (shown for recognition purposes) is below.

```
$ lualatex tex/sm.tex >& build.log
```

gave me

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Cygwin)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./tex/sm.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./WORK/sm/sm.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd))
*
```

**Update** Section 4.5 of the `listings` package documentation, specifically `\lstnewenvironment`, solves this... but you have to use a different syntax for the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum} % provide text around listings, to show indent
\lstset{numbers=none}
\lstnewenvironment{newlisting}{\hfill\minipage{\dimexpr\textwidth-1cm}}{\endminipage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{newlisting}
select *
  from foo
 where bar = 4;
\end{newlisting}

\lstset{numbers=left}

\begin{newlisting}
select *
  from foo
 where bar = 4;
\end{newlisting}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

gives me the output I'm looking for.

The critical bit, besides using the correct command (`\lstnewenvironment`) is to *not* use `\begin{minipage}{width} ... \end{minipage}`, but to use `\minipage{width} ... \endminipage`.

Comment: see the listings documentation, section 4.5 Environments.

Comment: this is the same as the standard verbatim environment and verb command, no such constructs work in the argument of another command or in standard definitions. But see Ulrike's link

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see section 4.5, but it does not demonstrate how to incorporate another environment (in this case `minipage`). I tried the obvious (`\lstnewenvironment{foo}{\hfill\begin{minipage}{4in}}{\end{minipage}}`) and had no joy. I think it's as @David says, Just Won't Work.

Comment: The `*` is the  prompt for more tex input, normally you could type `\end{document}` but as it is processing verbatim listings `\end{document}` would just typeset and give you a prompt again. (This gives a hint on why nesting listings is tricky:-)

Comment: No it will work I said to do what Ulrike says (Not that I ever do what she says:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My minimal tests suggest I can do some setup (`\lstset{keyworkdstyle=\itshape,numbers=none}` and override my global settings successfully (global are \underbar and left, respectively... to prove it works only). If I try to begin and end a minipage, I get the same result as before.

Comment: The problem so is not stated correctly: I suggested you change the title on "how to add a `minipage` in the starting code of `lstnewenvironment`" so that it could be removed from the duplicate list (@Werner)

Comment: @Rmano: That's not really necessary, as a `minipage`-like effect is also possible by changing the `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` keys.

Comment: @Werner better yet, `xleftmargin` (which I also overlooked, reading fail) meets my purpose without having to create a new environment. Still, how to create that new environment was not at all obvious, so I learned *two* things today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading page 43 of the documentation, and using the trick of replacing `\begin{env}...\end{env}` with `\env ... \endenv`(*):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL,keywordstyle=\underbar,numbers=none}

\lstnewenvironment{egdlisting}
{\minipage{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}}
{\endminipage}


\begin{document}

\begin{egdlisting}
select *
  from foo
 where bar = 4;
\end{egdlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...

---

(*) not sure if this is a documented thing or a dirty hack...

Comment: Oh! The missing piece! I'd forgotten about that method of starting and ending environments. Solved! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to be useful!